# regEx search/replace variable name without preceeding "_"

Tags: regex

in  project i would like to rename some private variable-names to incorporate a prefixed `"_"`.
e.g.: exchanging `"val"` to `"_val"`

However names with "_val" already exist.
Thus i used `[^_]val` in my search pattern.
This finds for example `"if (val =="` but replaces the `"("` giving me `"if val =="`

How do i need to change the pattern to:
Find all occurences of "val" without a preceeding `"_"` but do not replace the first character.

( hoping i explained the problem correctly - sorry if not )

Comment: in which language/tool? does it support look-behind?

Comment: i am using a textmate ( general regex search ), but bbedit grep search  is also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?<!_)val/
```

If you have access to [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Edit:**
Go for that then:

```
/([^_])val/
```

As you captured the character just before and made sure it's not an underscore, you can replace by something like:

```
$1_val
```

Comment: thanks for the help
however i do not seem to understand correctly what you mean with $1_val

Comment: $1 would refer to the 1st capturing group. In this case, the character you capture with `([^_])`

Comment: ah, ok, i see. 
but it seems my GUI-textclients do not support this feature.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to omit the slashes in my client ... now it works like a charming cheesecake